# How to authenticate and upload file via form with cURL

Tags: curl, command-line

I need to move a large file from a Unix server to a cloud storage service. The service doesn't provide any FTP or API to upload files. The only way to upload a file is to authenticate (username and password) and complete a simple form:

[image]

Once authenticated, to upload and submit the file I need to

1. Fill a compulsory form (`Enter delivery email address(es)`)
2. Click on `Browse...`
3. Locate the file in my computer file system
4. Click the big `Send` button

Would that be possible from command line with cURL?

Answer (score 1):

You need the endpoint that gets called when you click on Send. Also specify that it is multipart/form-data since you have both regular post parameters and a file.

```
curl -X POST [http://endpoint] -F "toEmail=email@provider.com" -F "image=@/home/Downloads/test.jpg"
```

Comment: How do I authenticate?